# Rails getter and setter functions not working with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My form looks as such on the `Profile` model:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email, "Email" %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>    
        <%= f.label :tag_list, "HELLO!" %>
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<%end%>
```

And I have a `Tag` model which I want to apply the tags to.

My getter/setter functions:

```
def tag_list
  Rails.logger.error "names"
  tags.map(&:tag_name).join(", ")
end

def tag_list=(names)
  self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
    Rails.logger.error "names"
    self.tags.where(tag_name: n.strip).first_or_create!
  end
end
```

And my controller:

```
def update
  redirect_to profile_path(params[:id])
end

def edit
end
```

It doesn't save the tags for that profile nor do I see my logs in the log file.

Comment: It looks like your update action does nothing but redirect. It needs to update the profile first.

Comment: @Sharagoz you're right. It seems that if I don't call `update` on the instance of `Profile` it doesn't trigger the setter method. Is that always correct?

Comment: Correct, the setters are not run until you call `@profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])`or a similar method.

Comment: Awesome. Want to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update action currently does nothing but redirect, so `@profile` is unchanged. The setter methods are not run until you call `@profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])` or a similar method.